# mod_rewrite existing directory

Tags: mod-rewrite

this is my mod_rewrite rule:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^./]+)/?$ index.php?id=$1 [L]
```

That will rewrite `http://www.mysite.com/abc/` to `http://www.mysite.com/index.php?id=abc`. However, I also have a sub directory in there that I don't want it to be rewrite. So if a directory exist, it should just use the directory. If not it will use the rewrite. How can this be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easy as pie:

```
RewriteEngine On
# Make sure it's not a real directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# Make sure it's not a real file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteRule ^([^./]+)/?$ index.php?id=$1 [L]
```

Hey by the way it took me 2s to find the answer: 2s = the time to type "rewriterule file does not exist"

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to include this below RewriteEngine On

```
RewriteBase /yourdirectory
```